# Print pair without introducing wrappers

Tags: c++, stl

I know that I could introduce wrapper(proxy class) to wrap pair and add overloaded << operator, but I I'am wondering why introducing '<<' operator for std namespace like below do not work?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iterator>
 #include <vector>
 #include <algorithm>

   namespace std{
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, pair<int, int>&);
   }

   std::ostream& std::operator<<(std::ostream& os, std::pair<int, int>& pi){
    os << pi.first <<", " << pi.second;
    return os;
   }

   int main(){
    std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > pi;
    pi.push_back(std::make_pair(1,2));
    std::cout << pi.front<<std::endl;
   }
```

Comment: Well, for one `pi.front` in `std::cout << pi.front<<std::endl;` isn't an object or reference therein; its a *method*. Think you mean `pi.front()` (in which case this *does* compile and do what you expect). Btw, you may want to make that object reference parameter to your operator overload `const`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is illegal:

```
namespace std{
 ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, pair<int, int>&);
}
```

you may only specialise a template class for function in the `std` namespace for user defined types.

You may not add overloads for user defined types to the `std` namespace.

This is an overload in namespace `std`.

anticipating:

> but what is the correct way?

This is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<class T>
struct tuple_printer;

template<class T>
auto tuple_print(const T& t) {
    return tuple_printer<std::decay_t<T>>(t);
}

template<class T>
struct tuple_printer
{
    tuple_printer(const T& t) : _t(t) {}

    void operator()(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << _t;
    }

    const T& _t;
};

template<class X, class Y>
struct tuple_printer<std::pair<X, Y>>
{
    using arg_type = std::pair<X, Y>;

    tuple_printer(const arg_type& t) : _t(t) {}

    void operator()(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << '(' << tuple_print(_t.first) << ", " << tuple_print(_t.second) << ')';
    }

    const arg_type& _t;
};

template<class T, class A>
struct tuple_printer<std::vector<T, A>>
{
    using arg_type = std::vector<T, A>;

    tuple_printer(const arg_type& t) : _t(t) {}

    void operator()(std::ostream& os) const {
        auto sep = " ";
        os << '[';
        for (const auto& e : _t) {
            os << sep << tuple_print(e);
            sep = ", ";
        }
        os << " ]";
    }

    const arg_type& _t;
};

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const tuple_printer<T>& tp){
    tp(os);
    return os;
}


int main(){
    std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > pi;
    pi.push_back(std::make_pair(1,2));
    pi.push_back(std::make_pair(3, 4));

    std::cout << tuple_print(pi.front()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << tuple_print(pi) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
(1, 2)
[ (1, 2), (3, 4) ]
```

Perfect, eh?

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple typo in your code:

```
std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > pi;
pi.push_back(std::make_pair(1,2));
std::cout << pi.front<<std::endl;
```

The last line should read:

```
std::cout << pi.front() <<std::endl;
```

note the difference between `std::pair<X,Y>::front` and `std::vector<X>::front()`.

As a side note, you should probably make your `operator<<` accept a *`const`* pair.